# What's the difference between Parent Contact Id and Contact Id for an Opportunity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I'm setting the `CustomerId` of an opportunity when I'm creating it to a `Contact`.  I was expecting the `ContactId` to be set to the `CustomerId`, but the `ParentContactId` is getting populated instead.  What is the difference between the `ParentContactId` and the `ContactId`?

Comment: btw, congrats for your 10k rep!

Comment: @GuidoPreite I'm guessing I'll be congratulating you in a month or two for the same achievement!

Comment: @GuidoPreite congrats on your 12k rep!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an official documentation about this, but I believe that `contactId` field is kept in the system for upgrade scenarios of previous versions (probably from CRM 3.0)

This based on the Metadata of the field https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328229(v=crm.5).aspx

The properties `IsValidForCreate`, `IsValidForUpdate` and `IsValidForAdvancedFind` for the fields `accountId` and `contactId` are all false.

In the other hand the same properties are true for the fields `ParentAccountId` and `ParentContactId`.

Comment: So the contact Id is only used as a carry over from older versions of CRM and is no longer being populated/used by CRM 2015+?  Only the ParentContactId (and accountId) is being populated?

Comment: afaik it's no longer populated by CRM 2011+. Only the parent fields are.